# Output Spark application name in driver log

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, apache-spark-standalone, spark2.4.4

I need to output the Spark application name (`spark.app.name`) in **each line** of the driver log (along with other attributes like message and date).
So far I failed to find the correct log4j configuration or any other hints.
How could it be done?

I would appreciate any help.

Using Spark standalone mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that seems to work involves the following two steps:

1. Create your custom `log4j.properties` file and change the layout.:

   ```
   ...
   # this is just an example layout config
   # remember the rest of the configuration
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=${appName}--%d{yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] [%c] - %m%n
   ```

   This file must be at the root of your class path (like in `src/main/resources` for most build tools) or edit `<spark-home>/conf/log4j.properties` on servers in your cluster.
2. Then set a property with the referenced key before bootstrapping your spark context:

   ```
   System.setProperty("appName", "application-name");
   SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("application-name")
   ...
   ```

In my quick test, the above produces something like this in all lines (tested in local mode):

```
application-name--2020-53-06 16:53:35,741 [INFO ] [org.apache.spark.SparkContext] - Running Spark version 2.4.4
application-name--2020-53-06 16:53:36,032 [WARN ] [org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader] - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
application-name--2020-53-06 16:53:36,316 [INFO ] [org.apache.spark.SparkContext] - Submitted application: JavaWordCount
application-name--2020-53-06 16:53:36,413 [INFO ] [org.apache.spark.SecurityManager] - Changing view acls to: ernest
application-name--2020-53-06 16:53:36,414 [INFO ] [org.apache.spark.SecurityManager] - Changing modify acls to: ernest
application-name--2020-53-06 16:53:36,415 [INFO ] [org.apache.spark.SecurityManager] - Changing view acls groups to: 
application-name--2020-53-06 16:53:36,415 [INFO ] [org.apache.spark.SecurityManager] - Changing modify acls groups to: 
application-name--2020-53-06 16:53:36,416 [INFO ] [org.apache.spark.SecurityManager] - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ernest); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(ernest); groups with modify permissions: Set()
application-name--2020-53-06 16:53:36,904 [INFO ] [org.apache.spark.util.Utils] - Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 33343.
application-name--2020-53-06 16:53:36,934 [INFO ] [org.apache.spark.SparkEnv] - Registering MapOutputTracker
...
```

Instead of setting the variable by hand in code, you may prefer to call `spark-submit` with something like

```
--conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-DappName=application-name'
```

For a more permanent change, you may want to edit `<spark-home>/conf/log4j.properties` (copy the template if the file doesn't exist) with the layout change, and call `spark-submit`/`spark-shell`, etc. with the system property.

Comment: Small remark: It seems there is no need to introduce `appName`, default variable `spark.app.name` can be used.

Comment: Oh that's great, thanks. I didn't know of that property.