# How to use Spark application name in logs?

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, hadoop-yarn

I am running Apache spark application in Yarn cluster. I use same application to trigger(spark-submit) multiple time with different parameters ( one of the parameter is `--name` ) and I have common log4j.xml file for logs.

I would like use some thing like `${spark.app.name}` in log4j.xml to different logs from individual spark jobs.

I tried using `${spark.app.name}` in log4j.xml but it is not working.

1. What I am doing wrong ?
2. Is there a better way to log spark application name in logs ?

Tried :
I tried using `${spark.app.name}` and `${spark.app.id}` in log4j.xml

Expect to happen:
Able to see spark job name in every line

What actually resulted:
Spark job name didn't appeared in log instead it was empty.

Note : I have gone through this question [Output Spark application name in driver log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097156/output-spark-application-name-in-driver-log). It is not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Used separate log4j config file to name for every spark submit script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use spark properties (`${spark.app.name}`) to configure log4j. This won't work.

If you have a value (`name`) to distinguish the jobs, you can set a system property and use it in `log4j.xml` file.

Use this variable in `logback.xml`: `${sys:logfilename}`

Add system property when the app is triggered:
`spark-submit -Dlogappname=App1 app.jar`

Comment: What will be scope of -Dlogappname jvm option ?
I will be running multiple spark jobs in a cluster